# What is dynamic facility location problem ans how to formulate the same? Please help

Tags: optimization, facility-location, logistics

Please explain how the problem solution looks like. basically I want model to dynamically give me multiple facility locations for a given demand.

Answer (score 4):

I am not a search engine, if you would search for "dynamic facility location problem" you would for example find [this book](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/227149037_Dynamic_Facility_Location_Problem) for free. Chapter 15 covers multiple formulations from the literature and describes them.